# Intersection between line and plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem: find intersection between the line passing through points A = (1,2,5) and B = (2,2,-3) and the plane x - y + 3z = 1.

My attempt:

AB = (2-1,2-2,-3-5) = (1,0,-8)

l = (1,2,5) + (1,0,-8)t

x = 1 + t

y = 2

z = 5 - 8t

Plug x,y,z into the equation of the plane to obtain 1 + t - 2 +15 - 24t = 1. Solving for t gives me 13/23 which, when plugged back into the parametric equation of the line, gives me (36/23,2,-69/23). My problem is that plugging those values into the equation of the plane does not give me 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $t=\frac {13}{23} $, we get

$$x=1+t=\frac {36}{23} $$
$$y=2$$
$$z=5-8t=5-\frac {104}{23} =\frac{11}{23}$$
and
$$x-y+3z=\frac { 36-46+33 }{23}=1$$

Comment: I see it now! I kept doing (5*23 - 8*23)/23 for some reason... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You get the point : $$\left(\frac{36}{23},2,\color{red}{\frac{11}{23}}\right) ;~\text{It's not}~\frac{-69}{23}$$ This satisfies the equation of the plane.$$x-y+3z=\left(\frac{36}{23}\right)-\left(\frac{46}{23}\right)+3 \cdot \left(\frac{11}{23}\right)=\left(\frac{36-46+33}{23}\right)=\left(\frac{23}{23}\right)=1$$